# How do you limit the Pitch of the UE4 and UE5 camera which is on a Springarm in C++

Tags: camera, unreal, unreal-5

I want to limit the pitch of the Player camera, which is connected to the spring arm attached to the player capsule.
[image: spring arm]
I **want to do this in C++ rather than Blueprints.**

Does anyone know how to implement this in C++ for the Unreal Engines?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the actual blueprint(s) you're referring to, rather than just including an external link, which may expire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rephrased my question in several ways and came up with a solution which I would lie to share.

In BeginPlay of the PlayerController add the code below.

```
APlayerController* ShooterPlayerController = Cast<APlayerController>( Controller );
if ( ShooterPlayerController )
{
    if ( ShooterPlayerController->PlayerCameraManager )
    {
        ShooterPlayerController->PlayerCameraManager->ViewPitchMin = -45.0;
        ShooterPlayerController->PlayerCameraManager->ViewPitchMax = 45.0;
    }
}
```